# Where is the latest link Eric meyer's reset? and pls explain his reset

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

- How many version are eric meyer
  created of his CSS reset
- and where is latest and
- what is difference in each version?
- and please explain his CSS reset's
  each declaration, What is the benefit
  of each selector?

Comment: This is about 12 questions, few of which relate to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you have a look at his blog? Eric Meyer is explaining his CSS Reset and what has changed between versions himself:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

As you can read on his [CSS Tools](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html) page his final CSS Reset found its way into the [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) framework. You might want to have a look at this, too.

Comment: Thx for reply it's 2007 version is this latest?

Comment: I updated my answer. While browsing his site I stumbled over the CSS Tools page where he shows his final CSS Reset version.

Comment: ok so eric meyer haven't changed in CSS reset since 2007.

Comment: i'm confused which is latest this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html or this http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

Comment: This one http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html is the latest as you can see from the date in the inline comment. But still I would advise you to have a look at the Blueprint CSS Reset.

Comment: @Stefan - but blueprint reset is little different http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/blueprint/src/reset.css

Comment: It is but the web did not sleep between 2008 and 2010. The Blueprint Reset CSS comes with HTML 5 specific tags, too.